# Can't push to the heroku

Tags: git, scala, heroku, intellij-idea

I was pushing the current git repository into the heroku.
That online application was developed using Scala and IntelliJ.
And I don't know how to fix this error.

```
$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 531 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote:  !     No default language could be detected for this app.
remote:             HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the         buildpack to use for this application automatically.
remote:             See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to salty-coast-14102.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/salty-coast-14102.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/salty-coast-14102.git'
```

Comment: Do you have `package.json` specified?

Comment: `package.json` is for Node.js apps, but this appears to be a Scala app.

Answer (score 47):

Read this doc which will explain to you what to do.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks

> #### Setting a buildpack on an application
>
> You can change the buildpack used by an application by setting the buildpack value.
>   When the application is next pushed, the new buildpack will be used.
>
> ```
> $ heroku buildpacks:set heroku/php
> ```
>
> Buildpack set. Next release on random-app-1234 will use heroku/php.
>   Run **`git push heroku master`** to create a new release using this buildpack.

This is whay its not working for you since you did not set it up.

*... When the application is next pushed, the new buildpack will be used.*

**`You may also specify a buildpack during app creation`:**

```
$ heroku create myapp --buildpack heroku/python
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But now it tells me `Failed to detect set buildpack https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/nodejs.tgz
`

Comment: have you placed the file under your root folder?

Comment: if its a node project you will also need the package.json under the root as well.

Comment: You should not have to set up a buildpack by default. Heroku will auto-detect supported languages (of which one is Scala). The problem here is that it does not detect Scala.

Comment: what if I don't want to set a buildpack? What if I just want to deploy some data files?

Comment: Any update on the fix? (Assuming we don't need to set a buildpack for python)

Answer (score 16):

If you are a `python` user -
Create a `requirements.txt` file preferably using `pip freeze > requirements.txt`.
Add, commit and try pushing it again.

If this doesn't work try deleting `.git` (beware this might remove the associated git history) and follow the above steps again.

Worked for me.

Comment: Thank you. I wish we would receive a more descriptive error message from Heroku for this.

Answer (score 15):

There has to be a `.git` directory in the root of your project.

If you don't see that directory run `git init` and then re-associate your remote.

Like so:

```
heroku git:remote -a herokuAppName
git push heroku master
```

Comment: @ciscokidx Please explain what your your solution does to fix the problem `No default language could be detected for this app.` . Your answer does not appear to be related to the question?

Comment: @JK It appears that Heroku requires the .git directory to be in the root folder as well.  This worked for me.

Comment: in provided logs git appers and git is orking, so this answer is fully unrelevant.

Comment: Had my app in a sub folder of the git repo, which caused the error described in the question. This answer helped me realise that I should move the app to root. Thanks.

Comment: Resolved my issue. I thought that using PyCharm, the project contains by default a .git directory but it doesn't. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 11):

Make sure you have `package.json` inside root of your project.
Happy coding :)

Answer (score 3):

If your app is a Scala app, it must have a `build.sbt` in the root directory, and that file must be checked into Git. You can confirm this by running:

```
$ git ls-files build.sbt
```

If that file exists and is checked into Git, try running this command:

```
$ heroku buildpacks:set heroku/scala
```

Answer (score 3):

Specify the buildpack while creating the app.

```
heroku create appname --buildpack heroku/python
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also select webpack build manually from the UI
[image]

Comment: from where i'll find this

Comment: @Dhiru, in the Settings tab.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the instructions displayed here, on your case follow scala configuration:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-scala#introduction

After setting up the getting started pack, tweak around the default config and apply to your local repository. It should work, just like mine using NodeJS.

HTH! :)

Answer (score -1):

If you are using django app to deploy on heroku

make sure to put **request** library in the requirements.txt file.