# Cannot push project to Heroku "no default language detected"

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I am trying to push a project to Heroku and I am receiving the error "no default language detected". My project is built on Node and the structure is as follows:

```
project/
  .gitignore
  Procfile
  server/
    package.json
    index.js
    ...etc
```

In my Procfile (since my package.json is not located in the project root) I have the following line of code:

`Procfile:`

`web: node index.js`

I am pushing by running:
`git push heroku master`

where I then get the error "no default language detected" and despite my best google/SO searching efforts, I cannot find a proper solution to get past this. What am I missing here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't push to the heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38841284/cant-push-to-the-heroku)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your package.json must be in the root directory. 
You can change the structure of your project or try to push a subdirectory of your project by running: `git subtree push --prefix server heroku master`

Comment: Ok, I reconfigured this and put the package.json file in my project root and ran npm install to get everything setup. It's working locally but when I run `git push heroku master` it gives me the same language error. Do I need to specify node beyond `"engines": { "node": "x.x.x" }` in the package.json?

Comment: ignore that last one. I didn't commit it. My bad. It's working now after following your instruction and committing the changes. thank you!