# Heroku cannot detect default language(python-3.6.4) even runtime.txt exists

Tags: python, django, heroku

I try to upload app and run on heroku
source files are below.
https://github.com/utahub/django_attend-managing-app/tree/heroku_check

with command

```
git push heroku heroku_check:master
```

but even thought runtime.txt exists in Root Dir, Heroku does not detect defauld language.

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote:  !     No default language could be detected for this app.
remote:                         HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.
remote:                         See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to uta-attend-managing-app.
remote:
```

I stacked with this problem for 2 days.
Please tell me why this is happened.

Thankyou in advance.

Comment: Note : with buildpack command, it successed, but is there anyway to deploy without buildpack command ? there are no qiita article which use buildpack, so i think something with my app looks wrong. I want to figure out i

Answer (score 1):

It solved.

i just mistake the file nem

Wrong   : requirement.txt
correct : requirements.txt

after corrected, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Someone asked this question already: [Can't push to the heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38841284/cant-push-to-the-heroku)

CodeWizard's solution:

Read this doc which will explain to you what to do.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks

> #### Setting a buildpack on an application
>
> You can change the buildpack used by an application by setting the buildpack value.
>   When the application is next pushed, the new buildpack will be used.
>
> ```
> $ heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python
> ```
>
> Buildpack set. Next release on random-app-1234 will use heroku/php.
>   Run **`git push heroku master`** to create a new release using this buildpack.

This is whay its not working for you since you did not set it up.

*... When the application is next pushed, the new buildpack will be used.*

**`You may also specify a buildpack during app creation`:**

```
$ heroku create myapp --buildpack heroku/python
```