# Why I'm hitting this error "[remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)"?

Tags: django, git, heroku

I'm trying to take my Django app live on Heroku but I'm hitting this 
error on "git push heroku master".

```
git push heroku master    
Counting objects: 231, done.    
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.    
Compressing objects: 100% (221/221), done.    
Writing objects: 100% (231/231), 739.46 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.    
Total 231 (delta 21), reused 0 (delta 0)    
remote: Compressing source files... done.

remote: Building source:    
remote:     
remote: !     No default language could be detected for this app.
remote: HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.    
remote: See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
remote:   
remote: !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:     
remote: !   Push rejected to aajkakaam.
remote: To https://git.heroku.com/aajkakaam.git ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error:  failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/aajkakaam.git'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git error when trying to push -- pre-receive hook declined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986139/git-error-when-trying-to-push-pre-receive-hook-declined)

Comment: `pre-receive` is a script deployed in the server-side repository. It is invoked by `git push`, usually used to test the code of the pushed revision. If the test fails, the push is rejected. You could ask the repository administrator for help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Heroku: No default language could be detected for this app for python even with runtime.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44232967/heroku-no-default-language-could-be-detected-for-this-app-for-python-even-with)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%5Bheroku%5D+%5Bdjango%5D+cannot+detect+the+buildpack

Comment: A solution for the same problems was offered here! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38841284/cant-push-to-the-heroku/50905814