# Error putting my github repository in heroku

Tags: heroku

sorry for the inconvenience, I am new to this heroku and try to upload my github repository, and it throws an error and I don't know how to handle it, I would like some help in this, thanks.

I will add a photo showing the error, so that it is displayed better.

[image: Error in heroky]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't push to the heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38841284/cant-push-to-the-heroku)

Comment: What's *in* your repository? How was Heroku supposed to know what to do with it?